# Reinstalling Ubuntu using WD Passport -- will I lose anything on the Passport

Tags: boot, usb, hard-drive

I want to wipe my computer clean and re-install Ubuntu from the start.  I have my files backed up to Google Drive, and while I don't have a USB stick or DVDs I do have a WD Passport.  I don't mind losing the files on the Passport but I do still want it to have the basic structure of a WD Passport rather than just some generic external disk, if that makes any sense.  I'm not sure if using my current Ubuntu's startup disk creator will damage the Passport in any way.  I'd appreciate any advice, or just a reassurance that by using the startup disk creator, the Passport will be basically unchanged.

I'm operating on Ubuntu 16.04, no partition, not sure if any other specs are relevant to this question.  When I plug the passport in it works just fine, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @lewis4u I'm putting the iso image on the external hard drive, but when I use the startup disk creater it prompts me that everything will be erased.  If that's just files, that's fine; but if it means it'll be wiped clean of anything that structures it as a WD Passport, I'd rather not do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your actuall question: Yes you will lose all your data, the installing media needs to be formated!

Normally a USB flash drive is used for installing OS.

In your case if data on that WD Passport is not important to you, you can use it as an "installing media".

Wiping data from it will NOT damage the drive. After you finish the installation you can reformat your WD Passport and use it as before.